# PyTube shows Internal Server Error when deployed on Render

Tags: python, flask, web, hosting, pytube

My **Flask** website uses **PyTube** to stream videos. It *works perfectly on Localhost*. When deployed on Render, *it was working fine*. Suddenly after a few days, it stopped working. It shows `Internal Server Error`. I updated Flask to 15.0.0, still getting the error.

requirements.txt

```
Flask==2.2.2
jwt==1.3.1
pytube==15.0.0
youtube-dl==2021.12.17
yt-dlp==2023.2.17
gunicorn
Werkzeug==2.2.2
```

A glimpse of the Log
[image]

Is there any way to fix this? Or did Render just stop allowing PyTube just like PythonAnywhere?